# delete many documents from mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I work on multitenant web application. It's necessary clear some container of users, which can be rather large, having many documents in collection.
I need to be able to delete many documents something like:

```
    return self::remove(array('LISTID' => $listId), array('safe' => true));
```

In some cases there can be many documents that meets this criteria, something like 100s of thousands or even millions. I worry that this operation can take much time and throttle server. 
If there are many documents, is it worth queue such operation to delete them offline something like pseudocode:

```
while (there are documents) {
  delete(1000 documents);
  sleep();
}
```

I wonder how to delete data by smaller portios in mongodb in this case. I also notice that for some reason deleting rather many rows takes place rather fast in mongodb, we have prototype with storing data in mongodb, deleting similar number of rows takes much longer in mysql, but in mysql each row in table has references to other table with data but even when therer are not records in dependent tables it seems much faster in mongodb, in mongodb it store all data in document, but it seems rather strange to me anyway.
Or maybe it's superfluous?

Thank you.

Comment: How many tenants do you have? If they are not in the thousands, you can have a collection per tenant and drop the whole collection (if want you are trying to do is delete all data for one tenant). Whatever you do, this almost certainly is an offline, batch-type operation.

Comment: It can be 10s thousands of tenants and even more. This operation should clear data of one list, tenants can have several lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something that you will have to do in your application. In PHP, you could f.e. do something like:

```
$found = false;
$ids = $collection->find(array('LISTID' => $listId), array('_id' => 1))->limit(1000);
do {
    $found = 0;
    $idsToDelete = array(); // we'll collect all the ids here, so that we can delete them in a batch
    foreach( $ids as $res )
    {
        $found++;
        $idsToDelete[] = $res['_id'];
    }
    $collection->remove(array('_id' => array( '$in' => $idsToDelete )));
    sleep(15);
} while ( $found );
```

You need to make really sure that you have an index on LISTID,otherwise the `find(array('LISTID' => $listId)` could make things really slow.

Comment: Isn't there are way to limit number of deleted documents in mongodb like in some database (for example  mysql) limit in remove operation.

Comment: Is this the only way do delete documents by smaller chunks in mongodb?

Comment: There is no limit on delete at the moment, so this is indeed the only way that I can think of.

Comment: It seems to me in your code getting 1000 more ids should be in cycle, right?